# Windows 7 black screen dual boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, debian, grub

I have a computer with Debian and Windows 7 installed in dual boot. When I turn it on I get the normal motherboard screen, then the GRUB screen and from there I can run Debian without any problems. But if I try to run Windows 7, after the Windows logo I get a black screen with the mouse pointer.

If I try to run in any type of safe mode via F8 I get the same result.

What I tried:

- Memtest from GRUB, doesn't detect any error
- If I run the Startup Repair from the system recovery options it will run for a while and then it says that it finished but it doesn't actually solve the problem
- I also tried to run chkdsk from the command prompt (from system recovery options) and it doesn't detect any error. If I run chkdsk /r it says that the disk is read-only
- Boot-repair from Debian doesn't solve issue (this is the summary: http://paste2.org/zCL65yPM)

I can access all the files in the windows partition from debian.
I don't have any restore point for Windows.

If possible I would like to avoid to overwrite my Debian partition to recover Windows.

What else can I try? Tell me if you need some other information about the system.

EDIT:
More precisely: after selecting Windows 7 in GRUB, I can choose between the various safe modes and the "normal" mode. I tried every one of them and they don't work. If I choose the safe mode it will stop after loading some drivers. If I run the normal mode it displays the windows logo and then I get to the black screen with mouse pointer.

Comment: Hey, nice to see you here! This is the right place.

Comment: Try to load Windows, when it started(well wait at least a couple minutes since you cant see where it is), then try to press Windows key(that located between Ctrl and Alt), hold it and press "P" wait at least a few seconds and try again. There might be 3 to 4 screen modes that you may try. This function switching GPU output, sometimes it happened with windows when it got stuck thinking that there is another primary monitor and the current one show up as a secondary one. Let us know if it works, so I will move this to the answer to help others who may get the same things

Comment: @Alex In the black screen I see there is the mouse pointer and it follows the mouse movements without any problem. I think that if Windows considered the monitor as secondary it wouldn't display the pointer. I'm right?

Comment: No, if windows see monitor as a second one you would see mouse movement on it, the same way if you connect a real one second display. Do one more experiment, try to make a right click on black screen, did it bring any menu?

Comment: @Alex I tried several times pressing Windows+P and then right clicking each time but nothing changed and menu did not appear

Comment: Then it something else... Ok, try to disable graphic mode in GRUB. Edit file `/etc/default/grub` and remove comment (# sign)from line  `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` then update settings `sudo update-grub` and reboot. If it doesn't help, try to check PCI settings and anything related to GPU (Reset to default probably would be the safest way) in BIOS settings

Comment: When I run update-grup I get some errors like "[165.xxxxxx] ext4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock" and "[165.xxxxx] qnx4: no qnx4 filesystem (no root dir)" and "[165.xxxxxx] fat-fs (sda2): bogus number of reserved sectors"

Comment: I tried rebooting after updating grub settings but it didn't solve the issue. Same thing for the reset of the BIOS default options. I added some information that was missing in the OP.

Comment: @Alex (It seems i'm not able to edit my previous comments)

Comment: Yes, you can edit comments only for 5 minutes after that it locked. Ok, download [HirenBootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) and boot it, there will be entries when it loaded in menu: boot from particular partition. It will bypass GRUB and should start Windows directly if you choose correct Windows partition. Would it be able to start this way?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is:

1. Reinstall Windows 7
2. Fix GRUB to take over dual-boot again using LiveCD 
   ([Recovering Ubuntu after Installing Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows))

Another solution:

1. Reinstall Windows 7
2. Use Windows boot manager to chain load Linux using a boot sector loader.
   ([Dual-boot Windows 7 and Linux](https://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html)) Here Windows boot manager controls dual-boot.